# What brand/model frame is this?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

This bike was given to me. I was just curious as to the brand?

[image]

(Click for larger image)

Comment: Did you ask the person who gave it to you, or whoever they got it from?

Comment: It's a fairly poor image -- not much detail.

Comment: For sure it's not a Focus bike !!

Answer (score 2):

It looks a lot like this [2000 Marin Mt Vision](https://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?Year=2000&Brand=Marin&Model=Mount%20Vision)
[image]

The front of the bike is very close.
The rear of the bike seems a little off

But then, given the clarity of the posted photo ....